# What is the equivalent of colorizing an object in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, colors, scenekit, scnnode

How can I animate a change in color of an `SCNNode`? In `SpriteKit` I would just use the `colorizeWithColor SKAction`, but that is not an option in `SceneKit`. In `SpriteKit`, I would typically have a collision between two nodes. When the nodes collided one of the nodes changed colors simply by running the `colorizeWithColor SKAction`. What's the equivalent of this in `SceneKit` for an `SCNNode`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the  `multiply` property of your material to achieve a similar effect. You can set the fade length with `SCNTransaction`'s `animationDuration` property.

```
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = yourFadeDuration
geometry?.firstMaterial?.multiply.contents = yourDesiredColor
SCNTransaction.commit()
```